# Transit time in Sydney Airport domestic to international

Tags: transit, short-connections, syd

I will be flying from Darwin to Sydney, arriving 7:40pm. Is there enough time to collect bags, go to international airport, check in and board a flight to Hawaii at 9:40pm (2 hours later)?

Comment: Which airlines are you using, and have you purchased two separate tickets?

Comment: When you say "go to international airport", do you really mean "go to international terminal"?  You'll already be at the international airport, SYD, unless your domestic flight is somehow arriving at some other obscure airport in Sydney?

Comment: @NateEldredge the domestic and international terminals at SYD are quite separate, and they have distinct train stations, which are called “International Airport” and “Domestic Airport”.

Comment: Hawaiian has only one daily SYD-HNL flight. If you miss this connection you'll be spending a whole day in Sydney regardless of how you booked the tickets. The next flight out of Sydney after that is 5:55pm the next day.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Hawaiian is not the only option, Jetstar also flies SYD-HNL.

Comment: @jpatokal Yes, that's the 5:55pm flight. Qantas codeshares with both of them.

Answer (score 1):

If these are two different tickets, I would recommend against it.

While it's not impossible, it's tight and you carry the full risk of missing the connection. If your flight from Darwin is delayed or if the bags are slow to come out, you will basically be a "no show" for your second flight and you may have to buy a whole new ticket to Hawaii.

You have to carefully check the check-in, bag drop, and be-at-the gate cutoff times of the airline for your departing flight. Bag drops typically close 45 minutes to one hour before departure, but every airline is different. Also make sure you do online checkin upfront, so you don't have to deal with that at the airport and already have a boarding pass.

There is some info on connecting in Sydney here: https://www.sydneyairport.com.au/info-sheet/get-to-your-next-flight but it mostly says "Talk to your airline", which is exactly what you should do.